# Record video on iOS and attach to email

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsurl, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to develop an app that can record video then attach it to email.
Here's what I did, but it isn't working.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        // Handle a movie capture
        if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
            if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath)) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self,
                                                    @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
                videoURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath] init];
            } 
        }
}
```

For Attachment:

```
[tempMailCompose addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] mimeType:@"video/MOV" fileName:@"defectVideo.MOV"];
```

The video recording and saving it to Photo Library is working good, my problem is the attachment.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For attachment in mail  use the following code :

```
[tempMailCompose addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] mimeType:@"video/quicktime" fileName:@"defectVideo.MOV"];
```

and rest of part is ok, i think.

Comment: Does it need to be uploaded first? and wait till it's over?

Answer (score 0):

For attachment you must use `NSData`. in case video attachment you have to use `MimeType @"video/quicktime".`

For more clarification please refer apple documentation.

[`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here:

I replaced this...

```
videoURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath] init];
```

With this...

```
videoURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:moviePath];
```

It's working now.